# rails each order with nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails application I  want to sort task by priority, the priority have the value p1,p2,p3,nil. If I sort like this

```
task..order(:priority).each do |t|
   puts t
end
```

The task which have nil as priority comes first, then other things are sorted based on order. I want task which have nil priority to go last on loop. How to accomplish this one?

I am using **mysql db**

Comment: maybe do not set priority to nil but use a default value that would be the highest priority ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Task.order('priority IS NULL, priority DESC')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
task = Task.order('priority DESC NULLS LAST')
```

Comment: I'm sure for POSTGRESQL, not sure for others.

Comment: It is for PostgreSQL only

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Task.order(priority: :desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `CASE` statement

```
Task.order('CASE WHEN priority IS NULL THEN p99 ELSE priority END')
```

change `p99` such that it will be last